# New SharePoint 2010 MUI package

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint 2010 and I want to now how I can create new sharepoint MUI language package or is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download language packs for almost 50 different languages here

SharePoint Foundation 2010 - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4731

Similar downloads are available for 2007 and 2007/2010 Enterprise.

Is your particular language not in that list?